# Conda can't install packages

Tags: python, anaconda, brian

I'm trying to follow [This](https://neuronaldynamics-exercises.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#setup) guide to install Brian2. I can create and activate the virtual environment but from step 3 I'm not able to install the packages.

I was trying to install with :

```
conda install numpy scipy jupyter matplotlib mpmath setuptools setuptools_scm mock nose
```

and the error I get is:

```
Solving environment: failed
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
    - python=3.1
    Current channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Please include the full error and how you're installing the packages.

Comment: Python 3.1 is long-since not supported. You should use a more recent version of Python.

Comment: I wonder if your conda is old. You might need to update it. I tried following the recipe, `conda create --name bmnn python` then `conda activate bmnn` then the `conda install ...` command you quote, and it's working fine for me, with Python 3.10.4`. If your conda installation is old, try installing a fresh one?

Comment: If you try to create a new environment with a more updated version of python, does the error persist? Something like `conda create --name myenv python=3.8`, `conda -n myenv install ...`

Comment: Oh, just looking at the list of conda channels in your error log, that's odd. `win-32`!? Are you trying to do this in a 32-bit Cygwin install? I'm doing it in the default Anaconda for Windows, which might be more likely to work. My channels look like `.../win-64` and `.../noarch`.